# Touchpad clicks after dragging on a link.

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I'm running out of search keywords for this problem. Honestly i'm not sure what to even call it.

If the cursor is over a clickable object, i can move the cursor a fair good distance, and when i lift my finger it clicks the link. A too long timer of sorts that waits for a tap?

Also happens when i right click and move the cursor to the menu, it clicks automatically when i lift my finger.

All the Universal Access mouse things are off, if that makes a difference.

I already battled to death to get my touchpad to work properly, when i finally found one comment from a guy with the same family of laptops that instructed me to build my own modified driver for it. It's an Alps touchpad by the way.

Comment: Did you check why `Universal Access mouse things` are off?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Sorry i don't understand? I just meant that it's not hover click or something that's causing it.

Comment: Not sure if I can help in any way, but what is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Output is 'default'

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like

```
gconf-editor
desktop.gnome.peripherals.mouse.drag_threshold
```

needs setting higher: mine's set to 8.That's how far you have to drag before it recognises it as an actual drag, and not just a click.

Which said, it doesn't seem to be a 'live' setting when I tweak it, and I don't see 'drag_threshold' anywhere if I run

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals | grep drag
```

All I get - if I change it in gconf-editor and then look for it - is:

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag true
```

which kinda confirms my opinion to move to KDE, now I've upgraded this old Ubuntu 16 box to 20 and compiz is broken.